# Who were Hogwarts teachers in the early 1900s?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

We know that Slughorn came to teach Potions in 1931, and Dumbledore taught DADA in 1908, but do we know the names of previous teachers (specifically those from years 1901 to 1908)? Who taught Transfiguration before Dumbledore?

(It's for a tabletop character's background in HP universe, I'm trying to stay as close as possible to the official lore).

Comment: How are we supposed to know this?

Comment: Pottermore, Rowling Q/A, mentions in books, etc.  I'm not saying the info is out there, necessarily, but OP wants to know if anyone has seen it.

Comment: Professor McGonagall Might be there, just a guess.

Answer (score 3):

## Galatea Merrythought was teaching then.

As Dumbledore tells Harry, Galatea Merrythought had been teaching at Hogwarts for nearly fifty years at the time the Dark Lord asked Headmaster Armando Dippet for the Defense Against the Dark Arts when he was eighteen.

> “Somehow, Harry knew the answer even before Dumbledore gave it.
>
> ‘Defence Against the Dark Arts. It was being taught at the time by an old Professor by the name of Galatea Merrythought, who had been at Hogwarts for nearly fifty years.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 20 (Lord Voldemort’s Request)*</sup></sub>

Since the Dark Lord would have been eighteen in around 1944, that’d mean Galatea Merrythought would have started teaching at Hogwarts in approximately 1894. She would have been teaching through the entire period between 1901 and 1908.

Comment: Do we know if she taught another subject than DADA at first? It seems she only took the post after Dumbledore became the Transfiguration teacher, as he was the DADA teacher before.

Comment: @Loukana It’s likely she did - Snape, Dumbledore, and Quirrell all changed the subject they taught, so we know it’s possible for professors to switch subjects. Dumbledore only says she taught for nearly fifty years, she could’ve changed subjects during that time. We don’t have any information about what other subject she could have taught, though.